# Upgrade maven deps (retrofit & okhttp) introduces "version managed" behaviour

Tags: java, maven, retrofit2

I have the following dependancies in my client jar:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
  <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
  <version>${retrofit.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
  <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
  <version>${okhttp.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

When I build it with these versions:

```
<properties>
  <retrofit.version>2.2.0</retrofit.version>
  <okhttp.version>3.9.1</okhttp.version>
</properties>
```

, the jar and dependancies are as expected. However, when I attempt to update to use latest versions

```
<properties>
  <retrofit.version>2.5.0</retrofit.version>
  <okhttp.version>3.13.1</okhttp.version>
</properties>
```

, the 2.5.0 retrofit version is imported, but okhttp version is 3.8.1 -

Inspecting

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

I can see this output -

```
com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.8.1:compile (version managed from 3.13.1)
```

, which I understand as meaning that the transitive dependency would have been 3.13.1, but 3.8.1 was explicitly asked for in the project's dependency management (but is was not)

Have reverted back versions, which is a pain, so any tips appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You do not have a dependencyManagement section in a pom anywhere, ideally in a parent pom? That is the recommended way to manage dependency versions across a project and should help to have fine grained control over which dependency version is forced into the dependency tree.

Comment: @Gimby - I do actually have a parent pom and it does have a  dependencyManagement section. I cant see anything in here that would override (if thats the correct desc) the okhttp:jar version. Thanks for advice though and I can see how a dependencyManagement could fix my issue, but am stumped as to why what i have does not work - and how maven is selecting okhttp:jar:3.8.1!

Comment: Basically you are creating the situation where you have the same artifact in the classpath twice, just with different versions. One of them has to go and it will be the first one that Maven sees that is the winner. I can't back that up with any written proof, but I have faith in the fact that Maven does not lie to you ;)